# How to include multiple log4j2.xml files in a project?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2, java.util.logging

My Project is composed of multiple modules. Each module can run on its own and have a separate log4j2.xml

Say Project X is composed of three modules:

1. Module A has log4j2.xml (contains Loggers and Appenders)
2. Module B has log4j2.xml
3. Module C has log4j2.xml

While integrating the modules, I have to manually copy-paste the **Loggers** and **Appenders** from each module's log4j2.xml into the project specific log4j2.xml file.

To avoid copy-paste, I've looked for **XInclude** to include multiple files but it supports only when Appenders and Loggers are in different file.
http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XInclude

How to do XInclude of multiple log4j2.xml files?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: They are using apache xerces as the xml parser and it does not support doing an include like that (ASFAIK). Its pretty much a dead project. The only solutions i know of are to write a custom configuration plugin(not an easy undertaking) or to use an xml preprocessor that supports xpointer includes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Log4j2 v2.6 release, composite configuration feature is added. With this feature, multiple log4j2 configuration files are allowed.

**References** 
- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-494
- https://github.com/Kamal15/Log4j2Examples/blob/master/src/main/java/in/co/nmsworks/log4j2/examples/CompositeConfigurationExample.java