# How can I separate logging configuration with log4j2 (1 config file per project) in a single application

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

My application consists of multiple projects which are integrated to run as a single java application.

I want to manage the logging separately in each project, using log4j2 (with slf4j as an interface). Every project would have its own log4j2.xml file, containing the logging configuration for that project's packages.
As I am aware of the singleton nature of the LogManager in log4j2 I don't see how I could realize this setup.
The child projects should independently load their configuration, without the parent project having to load all the config files of the children.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include multiple log4j2.xml files in a project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34671641/how-to-include-multiple-log4j2-xml-files-in-a-project)

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38408283/3151902)

Comment: Good point thanks. But I would like to configure log4j2 in the child projects without the need to set anything in the parent project (such as System.setProperty("log4j.configurationFile", "log4j2-A.xml,log4j2-B.xml,log4j2-C.xml");)

Comment: I updated the original description.

Comment: When I read the question it feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). May I ask why you would want to have a configuration for each project? I certainly would not want a library project to control the logging of an application which uses that library. I would also not want to rebuild the library each time I wanted to change the logging configuration.