# How to override Java resources when you run Spring Boot fat-jar?

Tags: java, spring-boot, fatjar

How to override Java resources when you run Spring Boot fat-jar?

I've created a Spring Boot far-jar that contains inside as resource a log4j.xml configuration file. Now when I run the fat-jar I'm trying to override it in this way

```
$ java -cp conf/ -jar target/myapp.jar
```

and I've put in the `conf/` folder a new log4j.xml. But nothing, it continues to use the resource inside the jar.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is only to define your own log4j.xml configuration file, this could help:

```sh
java -Dlogging.config='/path/to/log4j2.xml' -jar target/myapp.jar
```

(this was mentioned already in [How can I change the default location of log4j2.xml in Java Spring Boot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349309/how-can-i-change-the-default-location-of-log4j2-xml-in-java-spring-boot) )

If you just want to add resources by classpath addition you could refer to
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-executable-jar-format.html#executable-jar-property-launcher-features
where I found `loader.path` :

> loader.path can contain directories (which are scanned recursively for
> jar and zip files), archive paths, a directory within an archive that
> is scanned for jar files (for example, dependencies.jar!/lib), or
> wildcard patterns (for the default JVM behavior). Archive paths can be
> relative to loader.home or anywhere in the file system with a
> jar:file: prefix.

Comment: And if my base `log4j2.xml` include other configuration fragments? For example I have a specific fragments only for loggers, and I would like to override it only.

Comment: While reading https://stackoverflow.com/a/38408283/2590615 and the referenced links, I think you just have to add multiple parts comma separated. See https://github.com/kamalcph/Log4j2Examples/blob/0f460784140a2a2ccb831adafdc58659079e923f/src/main/java/in/co/nmsworks/log4j2/examples/CompositeConfigurationExample.java#L31